# How to use an object outside it's scope

Tags: java

im creating a pokemon battle game where i instantiate pokemon objects in if statements based on user input. This is obviously a problem, because I cannot use these objects outside the if statement, but there must be different pokemon objects that are created upon each user. I need a general way to use these objects and their methods, outside the if statement, or I need another way to create objects that vary from user input. Keep in mind i am a beginner at java, thanks, i need help, anyone help would be greatly appreciated.

The code is really long but here is a segment of it.

```
   if(answers == 1) {
      Gible pokemon1 = new Gible("Gible","Gabite & Garchomp", "Achieving Level 24","Dragon Type","Ground Type", "Slash, Tackle, Sandtomb, Dragonclaw", "Monster & Dragon", true , "Gabite & Garchomp", "Slash!", "Tackle!" , "Sandtomb!", "Dragonclaw!", 239, 189, 179, 189, 183, 320);
      System.out.println(pokemon1);
     }
     else {
      Squirtle pokemon2 = new Squirtle("Squirtle","Wartortle & Blastoise", "Achieving Level 16","Water", "None", "Tackle, Water Gun, Hydro Pump, Skull Bash", "Monster & Water 1", true , "Wartortle & Blastoise", "Tackle!", "Water Gun!" , "Hydro Pump!", "Skull Bash!", 195, 229, 199, 227, 185, 292);
      System.out.println(pokemon2);  

       }
```

The if statement is simply user input deciding which pokemon they want, (#1 or #2). The objects I am creating is tied directly to a subclass of an abstract class that returns a bunch of stats and info, (basically the stuff I put into the parameters).

Comment: Put your code please

Comment: 'outside *its* scope', typo in the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the object outside the `if` statements and then initialize it. So instead of this:

```
if (some test) {
    PokemonObject po = new PokemonObject();
    // ... use po
} else if (another test) {
    PokemonObject po = new PokemonObject();
    // ... use po
} else if (a third test) {
    PokemonObject po = new PokemonObject();
    // ... use po
}
// try to use po (doesn't compile)
```

Use this instead:

```
PokemonObject po = null;
if (some test) {
    po = new PokemonObject();
    // ... use po
} else if (another test) {
    po = new PokemonObject();
    // ... use po
} else if (a third test) {
    po = new PokemonObject();
    // ... use po
}
if (po != null) {
    // try to use po (works!)
}
```

EDIT: If you have specialized pokemon object classes, then you can define either a base class (that the classes can extend) or an interface (that the classes can implement) that defines the behavior common to all pokemon objects. Your code might then look like this:

```
PokemonObject po = null; // base class type for Gibble and Squirtle
if (answers == 1) {
    Gible pokemon = new Gible("Gible","Gabite & Garchomp", "Achieving Level 24","Dragon Type","Ground Type", "Slash, Tackle, Sandtomb, Dragonclaw", "Monster & Dragon", true , "Gabite & Garchomp", "Slash!", "Tackle!" , "Sandtomb!", "Dragonclaw!", 239, 189, 179, 189, 183, 320);
    // do Gible-specific stuff here
    po = pokemon;
} else {
    Squirtle pokemon = new Squirtle("Squirtle","Wartortle & Blastoise", "Achieving Level 16","Water", "None", "Tackle, Water Gun, Hydro Pump, Skull Bash", "Monster & Water 1", true , "Wartortle & Blastoise", "Tackle!", "Water Gun!" , "Hydro Pump!", "Skull Bash!", 195, 229, 199, 227, 185, 292);
    // do Squirtle-specific stuff here
    po = pokemon;
}
// do general Pokemon stuff here
System.out.println(pokemon.getName());
```

If using a base class rather than an interface, the base class constructor (or constructors) would accept only those parameters that make sense for all Pokemon objects. It would also only define those operations (like `getName()`) that are common to all Pokemon objects.

As an aside, your constructor calls seem extremely complex and error-prone. You might want to take a look at using the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) or related techniques to avoid constructors with [too many parameters](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074932/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-1-custom-types.html).

Comment: and as in this sample, that means you'd have a parent super-class for all pokemons

Comment: Object the the ultimate super-class

Comment: For example, System.out.println(po).

Comment: @johnnguyen - Well, you'd have to do something like `System.out.println(po.toString());`, but yes, it should work.

Comment: This would also work for methods and such right? like System.out.println(po.getName()); if you could, could you explain why just putting System.out.println(po) doesn't work?

Comment: not that i'm doubting what you're saying but I would like to know the semantics and understand it more conceptually and logically :)

Comment: @johnnguyen - Yes, it would work for methods (such as `getName()`). The reason you can't use `System.out.println(po)` is that the language rules allow for automatic conversion to a `String` (via a call to `toString()`) only in the special case of the binary `+` operator when the other operand is already a `String` object. (See [section 5.4 of the Java language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.4)). You'll often see things like `System.out.println("" + po);` to take advantage of this (although I personally prefer an explicit call to `toString()`).

Comment: @TedHopp Hi sorry for the delay, just another quick question, would i need a parent super-class for all the pokemons. and if so, what would go into it? because the reason why i have seperate pokemon subclasses is because they have special instance variables in their classes. Or is the parent super class Greg is talking about the abstract class because it somehow needs to take in parameters. Sorry if the question is confusing. If the subclasses have special instance variables, then how would the parent class take in all the different instance variables as parameters.

Comment: Or would it simply be better to make a bunch of pokemon objects null outside of the if statements? Edit, nvm this would not work as all the objects would have to have different names in order to not conflict with each other.

Comment: @johnnguyen - You should define either a (possibly abstract) base class (that all pokemon object classes can extend) or an interface (that all pokemon object classes can implement) that defines the common behavior for all pokemon objects. I'll edit my answer to sketch the mechanics of how this would work.

Comment: @TedHopp thank you for all the help so far. So then would this mean I would have to scrap the abstract pokemon class? because i need to have an abstract class as one of the requirements for my project :S.

Comment: @johnnguyen - Not at all. The abstract pokemon class is exactly the thing to use. I wouldn't have brought up the interface idea if I had known that using a base class was a project requirement.

Comment: @TedHopp what would go into the base class that the pokemon classes would extend? What would it look like, etc. Sorry for all the questions, but this is really helping me. Thanks.

Comment: @johnnguyen - It's hard to say without knowing more about your classes. The base class should contain everything that's common to all pokemon objects. For instance, I'm guessing that all pokemon objects have a name attribute, so the base class should contain a field for that, along with the method `getName()` to retrieve the value. (If the name can be changed, you'd also want a `setName()` method.) The derived classes inherit the name field (unless it was declared `private`, which might be a good idea) and also the name-related methods, so those would not be defined in each subclass.

Comment: @TedHopp alright thank you so much! With the clarity, I simply deleted all of the pokemon subclasses I had and remade 3 subclasses, Fighter1, Fighter2, and Fighter3 so that if i were to make an object for a class it could be simply referenced by fighter1 which i instantiate in the if statements. Anyways, thanks for all the help :)

Comment: @johnnguyen - Glad to help, and good to hear that it greatly simplified your code.

Comment: @Tedhopp anyway I could give you some +rep? I'm new to stack overflow :)

Comment: @johnnguyen - You can upvote any answers on StackOverflow that are helpful (whether or not they are answers to your own question). Just click the up triangle to the left of the answer. You can also accept one answer to each of your questions by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. Both of these actions provide +rep to the poster. Accepting an answer also gives you +2 rep.

Comment: Alrighty, thanks for putting the time out to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public Gible pokemon1;
public Squirtle pokemon2;
    if(answers == 1) {
          this.pokemon1 = new Gible("Gible","Gabite & Garchomp", "Achieving Level 24","Dragon Type","Ground Type", "Slash, Tackle, Sandtomb, Dragonclaw", "Monster & Dragon", true , "Gabite & Garchomp", "Slash!", "Tackle!" , "Sandtomb!", "Dragonclaw!", 239, 189, 179, 189, 183, 320);
          System.out.println(pokemon1);
         }
         else {
          this.pokemon2 = new Squirtle("Squirtle","Wartortle & Blastoise", "Achieving Level 16","Water", "None", "Tackle, Water Gun, Hydro Pump, Skull Bash", "Monster & Water 1", true , "Wartortle & Blastoise", "Tackle!", "Water Gun!" , "Hydro Pump!", "Skull Bash!", 195, 229, 199, 227, 185, 292);
          System.out.println(pokemon2);  

           }
```

and now you can call these 2 variables from every where.

Answer (score 0):

As Ted Hopp Suggested rather than having the declaration and instantiation inside the IF block you could declare the Objects outside the IF block and when you enter the IF block you can instantiate the objects.

```
GibleClass gb = null;
SquirtleClass sq = null;

        if(answer == 1){
        gb = new Gible("Gible","Gabite & Garchomp", "Achieving Level 24","Dragon Type","Ground Type", "Slash, Tackle, Sandtomb, Dragonclaw", "Monster & Dragon", true , "Gabite & Garchomp", "Slash!", "Tackle!" , "Sandtomb!", "Dragonclaw!", 239, 189, 179, 189, 183, 320);
        System.out.println(gb);

        } else {
        sq = new Squirtle("Squirtle","Wartortle & Blastoise", "Achieving Level 16","Water", "None", "Tackle, Water Gun, Hydro Pump, Skull Bash", "Monster & Water 1", true , "Wartortle & Blastoise", "Tackle!", "Water Gun!" , "Hydro Pump!", "Skull Bash!", 195, 229, 199, 227, 185, 292); 
        System.out.println(sq);
        }
```

Comment: Hi, the problem with this method is that i cannot "group" all the pokemon together because I will be using these pokemon for a battle scene next. And I need to set the pokemon instantiated as for example Fighter#1. And so because all the pokemon objects have different names because they will be instance variables, it  makes it hard to choose whatever pokemon was chosen as fighter#1. Sorry if it is a bit confusing

Comment: I tried using an arraylist of pokemons in which i added the pokemon objects i instantiated in the if statements to the array list. I then wrote (ArraylistName).add(objectname()); Then I tried to print out a getAttack method like so. System.out.println(ArrayListName)(0.getAttack()); and it couldn't find the getAttack method. Any fixed for this?